# PM2: what is 'version' and why is it always '0.1.0'?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using pm2 to control some node applications.
When I check pm2 apps using `pm2 ps`  I get an output similar to this one:

```
┌─────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name    │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ dlnk    │ default     │ 0.1.0   │ fork    │ 32210    │ 9s     │ 0    │ online    │ 7.4%     │ 61.7mb   │ fabio    │ enabled  │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

What is the `version` column for? Is it possible to change it using some field in the `ecosystem.conf.js` file?

Comment: What `pm2` version you are using? Are you sure you ran `pm2 ps`?

Comment: I am using pm2 4.2.3.  `pm2 ps` and `pm2 status` give me the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shows the version number in your `package.json` file.

Comment: what about namespace?